# Change what devices a UWP app targets

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, uwp

I want to my Windows UWP app to target only specific devices e.g. desktop and mobile. How do I specify that my app should only target these devices? I have found nothing of interest in the `Package.appxmanifest` file, and `project.json` only specifies what SDK's the app should use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two ways you can do it.

1 . Right click `Package.appxmanifest`, and click **View code**, you can find the following code in the `Package.appxmanifest`.

```
  <Dependencies>
    <TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Universal" MinVersion="10.0.0.0" MaxVersionTested="10.0.0.0" />
  </Dependencies>
```

You can modify the **Name** property to "Windows.Desktop" or "Windows.Mobile" to target a specific device type.

2 .When you submit you app in Windows Dev Center, you can specific you app are able to run  which type of device. 
   In **Pricing and availability** step, you can do it as follow:

[image]

I think you'd better choose the second way.