# Restrict Desktop support for Xamarin UWP application

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, publishing, xamarin.uwp

Is there a way to restrict the support for Desktop/PCs for the Xamarin UWP app published in Windows store. i.e, can we publish the Xamarin UWP app in Microsoft store which will list the app only in mobiles and Tablets and not list them in Desktop/PC devices?

Comment: remove reference for desktop family.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer to restrict mobile support, just adjust it as necessary to restrict it to only support mobile

https://stackoverflow.com/a/38096834/3183946

Comment: Does adding the below dependency will allow the app to be deployed in tablet like Surface tab.?
<TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Mobile" MinVersion="10.0.x.0" MaxVersionTested="10.0.y.0"/>

Answer (score 0):

> Does adding the below dependency will allow the app to be deployed in tablet like Surface tab.? 
>   `<TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Mobile" MinVersion="10.0.x.0" MaxVersionTested="10.0.y.0"/>`

[image]

From [**Device Family**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/get-started/universal-application-platform-guide#device-families) official document, PCs and **tablets** run the desktop OS, which is based on the desktop device family. Phones run the mobile OS, which is based on the mobile device family. So, if you only add `Windows.Mobile` in the `Dependencies`. It will not support Surface tab.

> Can we publish the Xamarin UWP app in microsoft store which will list the app only in mobiles and Tablets and not list them in Desktop/PC devices.?

If you uncheck `Windows 10 Desktop` option in the window store package configuration, and your app will not list in Desktop/PC and tablets devices.

[image]